# AJAX PHP form no reponse valid

Tags: javascript, php, json

I don't have an AJAX response, the script works fine but it stays on the PHP controller page. The form to be executed is inside a php loop. I tried a lot of things but I'm going in circles

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sendDelete').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#idEnter").html( id );
    $('#modalDelete').modal('show');
    $(document).on('click', '#confirmDelete', function () {
        $('#formDeleteQuantity-'+id).submit();
        $('#formDeleteQuantity-'+id).on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            var reload = document.location.href;
            $.ajax({
                url: $this.attr('action'),
                type: $this.attr('method'),
                data: $this.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    if(json.answer === 'ok'){
                        window.location.href = reload;
                    }else{
                        alert('Erreur : '+ json.answer);
                    }
                }
               }).done(function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
               });
            });
        });
    });
});

while ($last_data = $req_last_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $last_id = $last_data['id'];
    $last_idEnter = $last_data['idEnter'];?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form id="formDeleteQuantity-<?= htmlspecialchars($last_id, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>" method="post" action="/controller/deleteEnter.php" role="form">
                    <input type="hidden" id="idTool" name="idTool" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($id, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>">
                    <button type="button" id="sendDelete" class="btn btn-dark btn-index sendDelete" value="delete" data-id ="<?= htmlspecialchars($last_id, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>">Supprimer</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr><?php
}
$req_last_data -> closeCursor();
req_last_data = NULL;
```

Comment: You reload the page `window.location.href = reload;` upon success so everything is reset.

Comment: In your AJAX function, you're just telling it to refresh the page. If you want an "action" to run on the same page, you have to specifically tell it to run an action on the current page upon submit. `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` and then you also want the form to take default behavior if this is what you expect.

Comment: the action is done by an external controller after submitting the form it remains on the controller's page

Comment: How about putting your php in a different file (with all it's needs met within the post you are sending it? this way another file answers you , Also i don't see any part in the code which uses the $_POST in any way? how about calling a different file and for just a check just print_r($_POST); in that file to see if you receive any response - console.log it ofcourse.

Comment: I did not put the complete form to avoid weighing down the post

Comment: Regardless of how you set up the logic, simply telling it to refresh the page will do nothing, because it will just reload the page. All data will be lost. You need to tell your AJAX function that you're sending the data to a specific page (the same page in this case), and remove the `window.location`, otherwise, like already mentioned, you'll just reset the page, and you'll lose all of your data.

Comment: window.location I use it if the function is successful